# Google Analytics Enhanced Ecommerce - setPrice should be total or single?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I'm actually quite surprised I couldn't find an answer to this one, I reckon it should be a quite common question.

I have implemented analytics tracking to my application but the thing I can't figure out is whether the price set on product should be a single product price, or a final product price (quantity x singlePrice)?

So basically which one should I do out of below?

Let's say I have a product data and builder:

```
String productId = "123";
String productName = "Grimlock Action Figure";
String productCategory = "Toys";
String productVariant = "Transformers Robots in Disguise";
String productBrand = "Hasbro";
int quantity = 3;
double singleToyPrice = 19.99;
HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder builder = new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder();
ProductAction productAction = new ProductAction(ProductAction.ACTION_PURCHASE)
        .setTransactionId("1234567890");
```

Should I

a) Just add a product with price for a single unit

```
Product product = new Product()
        .setId(productId)
        .setName(productName)
        .setCategory(productCategory)
        .setBrand(productBrand)
        .setVariant(productVariant)
        .setPrice(singleToyPrice) // 19.99
        .setQuantity(quantity); // 3
builder.addProduct(product)
        .setProductAction(productAction);
```

b) Multiply the single price with quantity

```
Product product = new Product()
        .setId(productId)
        .setName(productName)
        .setCategory(productCategory)
        .setBrand(productBrand)
        .setVariant(productVariant)
        .setPrice((double) quantity * singleToyPrice) // 3 * 19.99 = 59.97
        .setQuantity(quantity); // 3
builder.addProduct(product)
        .setProductAction(productAction);
```

c) Add the product quantity times to the same transaction with single price

```
for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
    Product product = new Product()
            .setId(productId)
            .setName(productName)
            .setCategory(productCategory)
            .setBrand(productBrand)
            .setVariant(productVariant)
            .setPrice(singleToyPrice) // 19.99
            .setQuantity(1); // 1
    builder.addProduct(product)
            .setProductAction(productAction);
}
```

Just wondering which one will make analytics calculate the right amounts?

Best Regards,
DPD

Comment: You need to set the single product price (this is used e.g. in the product performance report where the single product price is multiplied by the total quantity from all transactions for that product).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested it, it's definitely (a). Thanks to @EikePierstoriff for help.

```
String productId = "123";
String productName = "Grimlock Action Figure";
String productCategory = "Toys";
String productVariant = "Transformers Robots in Disguise";
String productBrand = "Hasbro";
int quantity = 3;
double singleToyPrice = 19.99;
HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder builder = new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder();
ProductAction productAction = new ProductAction(ProductAction.ACTION_PURCHASE)
    .setTransactionId("1234567890");

Product product = new Product()
    .setId(productId)
    .setName(productName)
    .setCategory(productCategory)
    .setBrand(productBrand)
    .setVariant(productVariant)
    .setPrice(singleToyPrice) // 19.99
    .setQuantity(quantity); // 3
builder.addProduct(product)
    .setProductAction(productAction);
```

This one can be resolved/closed now.